# Mobile app and server side database

Tags: javascript, cordova, mobile, pouchdb

I have a mobile app built using cordova and it talks to server via REST API. The app has been designed to work offline and online mode hence app needs to have its own local database.

The server side DB is SQL server and I am looking for some fast lightweight and reliable DB to store data locally in app. CouchDB and PouchDB both require same DB at the server side hence they are out of question.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that any offline storage is not ultimately reliable, your users can always clear their cache if they want to.

You could have a look at a few other possibilities:

- http://mozilla.github.io/localForage/ - has a localstorage-like api
- http://www.dexie.org/ - A nice interface to using IndexedDB
- http://google.github.io/lovefield/
- http://dev.yathit.com/ydn-db/index.html

Taken from: http://pouchdb.com/2015/09/01/pouchdb-4.0.1-gotta-go-fast.html specifically 'What you can do about performance'

Make sure you check the browser support of those libraries.

<3 from the PouchDB community